# how to set vertexZ or proper zorder in isometric tilemap in cocos2d-x/ how to apply proper depth management in isometric tilemaps in cocos2d-x

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, depth-buffer

i was working with isometric tilemap in cocos2d-x and one problem i'm facing is related to depth management. Player sprite is not properly hiding behind the trees and houses that are placed on different layers of tilemap. I've applied **cc_vertexz = -1000** to **background** and **automatic** to **house and enviornment layer** and i'm setting vertexZ using below method which is called by update.

```
void HelloWorld::repositionSprite()
{
CCPoint p = playerSprite->getPosition();
p = CC_POINT_POINTS_TO_PIXELS(p);
float newZ = -(p.y+16) /16;
playerSprite->setVertexZ( newZ );
```

}

I also enabled the following in AppDelegate class.

**CCDirector::SharedDirector()->setDepthTest(true);
  CCDirector::SharedDirector()->setProjection(kCCDirectorProjection2D);**

but still cant get the appropriate solution, please help me and let me know what i'm missing.

Comment: for vertexZ to work you have to enable depth buffering, this should be in the CCGLView initialization

Comment: Are you talking about depthFormat?

Comment: yes, depthFormat equals depth buffering

Comment: it is already enabled in AppController.mm in method **applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions**, what else do you think i'm missing in coding part?? i've posted my code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Tile Coordinate are in format like (x,y)

```
                         (0,0)
                      (1,0) (0,1) 
                   (2,0) (1,1) (0,2)
                (3,0) (2,1) (1,2) (0,3)

        So on........

    int a= _tileCor.x + _tileCor.y;
   _playerSprite->setZorder(a);
```